# Convert string to array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How to convert a string into an array of the object?

```js
 let str  = `<%-found%>`;
                    let result = [];
                    JSON.parse(`["${str}"]`.replace(/},{/g, `}","{`)).forEach((e) => {
                        result.push(JSON.parse(e.replace(/{/g, `{"`).replace(/:/g, `":`).replace(/,/g, `,"`)));
});

`<%-found%>` = "{SPOT:0,0:10,1:0},{SPOT:1,0:5,1:5}"
```

***show this error:***

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token   in JSON at position 3
> at JSON.parse ()
> at (index):2010

Comment: What is going on here? `\`["${str}"]\`` That's not escaped properly. That should be `JSON.stringify([str])` but I don't know why you'd then go on to mangle it with regular expressions and turn it into something...apparently not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a messed up JSON string you have there. But it seems like your code is already working when I remove that strange reassignment you have at the beginning.

```js
let str = "{SPOT:0,0:10,1:0},{SPOT:1,0:5,1:5}";

let result = [];
JSON.parse(`["${str}"]`.replace(/},{/g, `}","{`)).forEach((e) => {
    result.push(JSON.parse(e.replace(/{/g, `{"`).replace(/:/g, `":`).replace(/,/g, `,"`)));
});

console.log(result);
```